# Everywhere bootable USB key (full install)?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I've installed UBUNTU on a USB key (not a live installation but a full installation instead with encryption) and I can successfully boot the key from standard laptops.
What I haven't been able to do is to boot the same key on a MacBook.
I know MacBooks and new generation laptops use UEFI specifications, so I've tried to create a partition in which I've install rEFInd boot manager.
I am able to see the partition when booting from a MacBook but then I get some errors and I cannot proceed any further.
I am aiming to have a full linux installation on a USB key that I can boot anywhere (especially MacBooks). 
Does anybody know if this is doable and how can be done?

Comment: Fundamentally, you need to install both a BIOS/CSM/legacy boot loader and an EFI boot loader on your USB drive. The latter will require using the fallback filename of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html#alternative-naming) I'm sure this topic has been covered here before, but I'm having trouble finding a relevant question and answer.

Comment: I've just checked the EFI boot loader is correctly install with the right fallback name. In fact I have the feeling that the boot loader starts correctly but then returns this  "Error: Not found while loading legacy loader"

Comment: The message about a "legacy loader" implies that something could not find a BIOS/CSM/legacy boot loader. EFI-mode GRUB cannot switch modes to BIOS/CSM/legacy booting, and so almost certainly did *not* generate that error message. Instead, that sounds like an error message from the firmware, or possibly from rEFIt or rEFInd, if one of them is in the mix.

Comment: yes rEFInd is installed in one partition in the path EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi
I am now installing El Capitan to see if I get the firmware updated. It may fix the issue.

Comment: You might want to install the EFI driver for whatever filesystem holds your Linux kernel (probably ext4fs). That way, rEFInd should be able to start Ubuntu by launching the kernel directly, bypassing GRUB. The easiest way to install the EFI driver is to boot to OS X, insert the USB drive, and re-install rEFInd via the `refind-install` script.

Comment: If I run the script, am I going to create a specific boot manager in my USB key or am I going to change the default boot manager of my MacBook? I just want to make sure I am not going to modify anything on my macbook as it's my work laptop

Comment: I mis-read your statements; I thought you meant you already have rEFInd installed on your boot disk. Running `refind-install` will install rEFInd on your hard disk, unless you use certain of its options, in which case it could be installed to a USB drive.

Comment: I am just aiming to have a USB key with linux installed (non-live) that I can boot almost everywhere (or at least on my macbook).

Comment: I have updated to El Capitan but I still get the same error. 
This is my usb key config
52.4 MB    disk2s1 (FAT32, for the rEFInd files)
64.0 GB    disk2s3 (FAT32, just for common files)
248.5 MB   disk2s5 (BIOS boot loader)
56.0 GB    disk2s6 (for the OS, encrypted)
7.7 GB     disk2s7 (SWAP)
The first thing I need to understand is whether this config is supposed to work because in this case I stop trying to fix the usb key.

Comment: It's is (somewhat) possible, but it requires a deep understanding of both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode booting. For the latter, please read [Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) and [My page on EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html).

Comment: I've been able (God knows how), to  boot on MacBook. The problem now is that during the boot something fails and I end up in initramfs. There are few things I did to get here: 
- change the partition map to GPT
- activate the boot flag on the partition that hosts rEFInd
- install the right version of the OS (amd64)

Comment: Final comment: everything works fine now.
I've removed rEFInd and I've followed the instructions on this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276498
Then I took the GRUB config file of my BIOS Boot Loader default install and copy it in the EFI one.

Answer (score -1):

I think it isn't possible. Full installation of an OS is strictly connected to the hardware on which is installed.

Consider a live USB key with persistence, it isn't like an installed OS but it permits to save and store files.

Comment: No, Ubuntu's pretty good about *not* linking itself to a particular piece of hardware. The big challenge that John Doe is facing is in setting up the boot loader.

Comment: Yes the problem is settin up the boot loader.
Bios boot loader works fine but I have problems with the Efi. 
I will post the error i get as soon as I can.

Comment: Error is "Error: Not found while loading legacy loader"